# is ubuntu server still running on vmware when laptop is closed

Tags: 18.04

So i was wondering something about the ubuntu server. If I have an ubuntu server on a vmware on my laptop which have apache running a website. If I would be closing the lid on my laptop (with standard lid closing settings on laptop), would the website then still be up and running, or do I have to have the lid up at all time then?

Comment: We don't know what is the OS and what is "standard lid closing settings on laptop". Most likely it won't run.

Comment: Test it. Run a looping script which adds the time into a file, launch the script, close the lid. Open the lid a minute later, stop the script. look in the script, see what happened.

Answer (score 1):

By default closing the lid goes into suspend state (Which means your system will not run those website(httpd) services.).

You can install/open the power management options in ubuntu to configure these values.